# Gulp with webpack-dev-server

Tags: reactjs, gulp, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2, react-hot-loader

I recently try to make a boilerplate for webpack2 + babel6 + gulp + react-hot-loader project. I started by forking [react-hot-loader-minimal-boilerplate](https://github.com/wkwiatek/react-hot-loader-minimal-boilerplate). Then I added a gulpfile to it as [this branch](https://github.com/yookoala/react-hot-loader-minimal-boilerplate/tree/gulp).

If you read the code, you'll find I've only added the last 1 commit, which added the gulp package, gulp file and add the `npm run gulp` script. You 'd want to take a look at [gulpfile.babel.js](https://github.com/yookoala/react-hot-loader-minimal-boilerplate/blob/gulp/gulpfile.babel.js), which currently looks like this:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const cfg = require('./webpack.config');
const devServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
const path = require('path');
const util = require('gulp-util');

gulp.task('dev', () => {
  cfg.plugins = [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  ];
  cfg.entry = {
    'app': [
      'babel-polyfill',
      'react-hot-loader/patch',
      'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
      './src/index',
    ],
  };

  new devServer(webpack(cfg), {
    //contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    //publicPath: cfg.output.publicPath,
    stats: {
      colors: true,
    },
  }).listen(8080, 'localhost', function (err) {
    if(err) throw new gutil.PluginError("webpack-dev-server", err);
    util.log(`'${util.colors.cyan('dev:server')}' http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/index.html`);
  });
});
```

Supposedly, the command `npm run dev` and `npm run gulp` should have the same effect. But in reality, the `gulp` command is not working.

- If I change my React code, the code in browser should update accordingly.

  The console log for code update in `npm run dev`:
  [image: console log for <code>npm run dev</code>]
- Instead, although the browser did get signal from webpack-dev-server for the update, the DOM is not updated along with the signal.

  The console log for code update in `npm run gulp`:
  [image: console log for <code>npm run gulp</code>]

Any suggestion on how to fix this boilerplate?